# Connection has been terminated - public server from localhost by proxylocal gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, server, firewall, proxylocal

i am stuck with this problem for a some time. I am developing a rails app with facebook oauth login and `open graph stories`.

But to test the `open graph` i think facebook wants a public server to access my app. And then i found out this `proxylocal` gem which will make my localhost to a public server. [proxylocal.com](http://proxylocal.com)

I successfully installed it by `gem install proxylocal` and when i try to start it by `proxylocal 3000` it says **Connection has been terminated**

[image]

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/proxylocal/proxylocal-gem/issues/2) may helpful

Comment: I tried...i have firewall turned off on my system. Still it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the alternate and it works fine. [Pagekite](https://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/)

Answer (score 2):

We can use  [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) for creating local proxy and access to same/another network. We should need to follow below steps -

1. Download from below link as per your requirement

   > https://ngrok.com/download
2. Unzip it

   > $ unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip
3. Run command on terminal (I am assuming your application is already
   running on 3000 port ) -

   > $ ./ngrok http 3000
4. When you run above command then able to see new ngrok console screen -

   > Copy Forwarding url and use it as proxy URL.